# how to distinguish between buttons with same className

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day! I'm very new to Front-End development, and as a part of my homework I have got to use pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript only to make next thing:
6 button (likes) with same class name. I have different background images for one that wasn't clicked and one that was. In Demo I have `background-color` instead, does not matter I guess.

```
let pageCont = document.querySelector(`.page`);
let mainCont = pageCont.querySelector(`.container`);
let tableCont = mainCont.querySelector(`.table`);
let tableElem = tableCont.querySelector(`.table__element`);
let elemCont = tableElem.querySelector(`.table__text-container`);
var likeIcon = elemCont.querySelectorAll(`.table__like-icon`);

for (var i = 0; i < likeIcon.length; i++) {
    likeIcon[i].addEventListener('onclick', function likeIconIsClicked() 
    {
        likeIcon.classList.toggle(`table__like-icon_active`);
    }
    );
}
```

The idea was to change button(table__like-icon --> table__like-icon_acitve) properties. If I use `` var likeIcon = elemCont.querySelector(`.table__like-icon`) `` instead of `querySelectorAll`, I will be able to change only first found button which is not correct. So I used code that I had found on StackOverflow and tried to use it. Didn't work much. Here is the **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gasparilla/9cL7ua4r/11/

Can someone help me out?

Comment: First of all, there's no `onclick` event Listener. Rather it's `click`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `This` keyword, specifies the caller of a function, in this case the button the user clicked on. From there on, you can change the properties of the element using the `This` keyword.

Here's a quick reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

```js
var likeIcon = document.querySelectorAll(`.table__like-icon`);

for (var icon of likeIcon) {
  icon.addEventListener('click', likeIconIsClicked);
}

function likeIconIsClicked() {
  this.classList.toggle(`table__like-icon_active`);
}
```

```css
.table__like-icon_active {
  background-color: blue!important;
}

.table__like-icon {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  //your custom class including background-image: ,...
}
```

```html
<button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
<button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
<button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `forEach` that could remember the icon reference in every loop.

```js
var likeIcons = document.querySelectorAll(`.table__like-icon`);

likeIcons.forEach(icon => { // change from `for` to `forEach`
  icon.addEventListener('click', function() { // change from 'onclick' to 'click'
    icon.classList.toggle(`table__like-icon_active`);
  });
})
```

```css
.table__like-icon{
    width: 21px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: auto 22px auto auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;
    border: 0 none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.table__like-icon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table__like-icon_active{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="table">
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="./images/kirill-pershin-1088404-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">FirstButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="./images/kirill-pershin-1404681-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">SecondButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="./images/kirill-pershin-1556355-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">ThirdButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="./images/kirill-pershin-1404681-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">forthButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="images/kirill-pershin-1556355-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">fifthButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__element">
    <img
      src="./images/kirill-pershin-1088404-unsplash.png"
      alt=""
      class="table__image"
    />
    <div class="table__text-container">
      <h2 class="table__title">sixthtButton</h2>
      <button class="table__like-icon" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you looking for a way to detect which button click and perform operations on that button
here you go

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (!event.target.matches('.table__like-icon')) return;
  // do what ever you want to do
  // event is your desire clickable button event.
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Here it will listen every click inside document. In If condition i am returning all the click event except that i want on .table__like-icon.